# Differences in random functions

Tags: java

I am creating a random number from 1-100, I was looking at some Stackoverflow questions to look for the proper way and I got confused by the many different suggestions.
What is the difference between using this:

```
    int random= (int)(Math.random()*((100-1)+1));
```

this:

```
int random= (int)(Math.random()*(100);
```

and this:

```
    int random= 1+ (int)(Math.random()*((100-1)+1));
```

Comment: Well, the first two are equivalent (besides the mismatched parenthesis) and return an integer between 0 and 99 inclusive, and the second returns an integer between 1 and 100, inclusive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, he's asking for which one is the correct and / or the logic of each

Comment: This question amounts to "What's the difference between `((100-1)+1)` and `100`?" and "What difference does adding 1 to an expression make?".  I wish there were more thought put into some Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int random = (int)(Math.random()*(x);
```

This sets `random` equal to any integer between `0` and `x - 1`.

```
int random = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*(x);
```

Adding `1` to the overall expression simply changes it to any integer between `1` and `x`.

```
(int)(Math.random()*((100-1)+1))
```

is redundant and equivalent to

```
(int)(Math.random()*(100)
```

So take note that:

`1 + (int)(Math.random()*(x)` returns an `int` anywhere from `1` to `x + 1`

but

`(int)(Math.random()*(x + 1)` returns an `int` anywhere from `0` to `x + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you use [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [nextInt(100)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) like so,

```
java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
// 1 to 100, the 100 is excluded so this is the correct range.
int i = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
```

it has the added benefit of being able to swap in a more secure random generator (e.g. [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)). Also, note that you can save your "random" reference to avoid expensive (and possibly insecure) re-initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The first is equivalent to the second. Both will give a random integer between `0` and `99` (inclusive, because `Math.random()` returns a `double` in the range `[0, 1)`). Note that `(100-1)+1` is equivalent to `100`.

The third, will give an integer between `1` and `100` because you are adding `1` to the result above, i.e. `1` plus a value in the range `[0, 100)`, which results in the range `[1, 101)`.